# Jitsi meet connection doesn't established

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jitsi-meet

[As the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxqjT.png)
I try to setup connection jitsi-meet but it won't run onConnectionSuccess. [This is the log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ajjcs.png)
Does anyone know how to setup jitsi connection? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you have to add bosh url too in the options

```
var options = {
hosts: {

 domain: 'beta.meet.jit.si',
muc: 'conference.beta.meet.jit.si' // FIXME: use XEP-0030
},
 bosh: '//beta.meet.jit.si/http-bind', // FIXME: use xep-0156 for that

// The name of client node advertised in XEP-0115 'c' stanza
 clientNode: 'https://beta.meet.jit.si'
};
```